# For modifying MPEG-2 Part 4 video, which is the easiest library/approach can I use?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mpeg, mpeg-4

I'm trying to implement a video watermarking system which modifies a subset of individual pixels (i.e. the RGB values at sets of `x,y`). The base use case would be modifying an MP4, which consists of modifying the contained MPEG-2 Part 4 Video stream.

I've done some research, and have found that it isn't as simple as just modifying the raw frames, as the ubiquitous [P-frames and B-frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types) rely on compressing the output by only storing the differences between frames.

I'm relatively technology-agnostic, I just want to find a solution. Which library/framework should I use (seems like ffmpeg for now) and which approach do I take?

Answer (score 0):

Watermarking can be achieved by "overlay" feature of FFMPEG. You can check this quick & simple [tutorial](http://ksloan.net/watermarking-videos-from-the-command-line-using-ffmpeg-filters/).